# How to include and use tinymce in a svelte component?

Tags: tinymce, svelte

I want to include an external rtf component in my svelte app.

I tried adding tinymce using the cdn in template.htm and then creating the following svelte component. The editor renders, however I can't get data into or out of the editor.

```html
<script>
  import { onMount, tick } from 'svelte'
  export let label = ''
  export let value = ''

  $: console.log('value', value)

  onMount(() => {
    tinymce.init({
      selector: '#tiny',
    })
  })
</script>

<p>
  <label class="w3-text-grey">{label}</label>
  <textarea id="tiny" bind:value />
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Super old but encountered this today and found a solution.

#### Solution:

```html
<svelte:head>
    <script src="https://cdn.tiny..."></script>
</svelte:head>

<script>
import {onMount} from 'svelte';
let getHTML;
let myHTML;
onMount(() => {
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#tiny'
    })

    getHTML = () => {
        myHTML = tinymce.get('tiny').getContent();
    }
})
</script>

<textarea id="tiny" bind:value />

<!-- click to get html from the editor -->
<button on:click={getHTML}>Get HTML from TinyMCE</button>
<!-- html is printed here -->
{myHTML}
```

#### Explanation:

My initial thought was to bind per normal with

```html
<textarea bind:value></textarea>
```

but that doesn't work *I think* because tinyMCE is doing complicated stuff in the background. Instead of adding the cdn reference in `template.htm` I used `<svelte:head>` so it only is loaded for this component. The function `tinymce.get('...').getContent()` must be called to get the contents of the editor, but it requires tinyMCE, so it must be called within the onMount. So I define a function `getHTML` within onMount. Now `getHTML` can be used anywhere to assign the contents of the editor to `myHTML`.

Comment: Only problem with including  <script src="https://cdn.tiny..."></script> in the svelte:head tag it will be added for every instance of your component.

Answer (score 0):

step one:

run this command on in your terminal

```
    npm install @tinymce/tinymce-svelte
```

(reference for installation : https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/svelte/)

step two :

```
  <script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    let myComponent;
    let summary='';  

   
    onMount(async()=>{
            const module=await import ('@tinymce/tinymce-svelte');
            myComponent=module.default;
    })
  </script>
```

step three :

```
<svelte:component this={myComponent} bind:value={summary}/>
{@html summary}
```